# grid layout with JPanels java

Tags: java, swing, panel

I am trying to create a program in Java that is sort of like a board game. I have gameTiles, currently with only one color as I try to get the layout right. I want the tiles to appear about halfway of the width of the window and extend to the bottom, maybe anywhere from 9x9 or 11x11 different tiles. I have tried to use the grid layout to get these to be close together, not necessarily touching but close enough to look like a board game. However, no matter what I try, the tiles are space so far apart, and change shape when I resize window. I have been using the GridLayout manager to try to achieve this. Here is my code.

```
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    public class GameWindow extends JFrame {

public GameWindow(String title){
    super(title);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(1200,400);
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GameWindow gameWindow = new GameWindow("Game");
    gameWindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));
    GameTile greenTile = new GameTile(0,true,0,10);
    GameTile greenTile2 = new GameTile(0,true,0,10);
    gameWindow.add(greenTile);
    gameWindow.add(greenTile2);
    gameWindow.setVisible(true);
}
    }
```

This is the GameWindow.java file. The GameTile.java I have so far (which is still mainly not finished just for testing) is as follows:

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Image;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    /**
    * @author Zachary Parks
    *
    */
    public class GameTile extends JPanel {
    private Color color;
    private Color[] colors = {Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW, Color.BLACK};
    private int score, multiplier,initialX,initialY;
    private boolean positiveEffect;

    public GameTile(int colorTile, boolean effect, int initX, int initY){
    color = colors[colorTile];
    score = getScore(color);
    multiplier = getMultiplier(color);
    positiveEffect = effect;
    initialX = initX;
    initialY = initY;
    }
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Image image = null;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("greentile.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     g.drawImage(image,initialX,initialY,this);
    }

    private int getMultiplier(Color color2) {
    return 0;
    }

    private int getScore(Color color2) {
    return 0;
    }
    /**
    * Method that returns the data from the tile in 
    * array of int. 0 index = added score, 1 index = tile effect score
    * @return
    */
    public int[] getData() {
    int [] scoreData = null;
    scoreData[0] = score*multiplier;
    return null;    
    }
    }
```

A lot of the code is still in progress, like the GameTile's properties, all I'm trying at this point is get the tiles next to each other.
This is what I am getting:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/nXfrYSU.png]

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Your battery is at 94%, plug in a cable?

Comment: Don't do file I/O in a painting method. The image should be read in the constructor of your class.

Comment: Do you really need those panels and layout manager ? If you are looking for simple board kind of why not simply draw and fill squares of 9x9 or 11x11 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add tiles like a grid. A `tileSize` variable is great to have. Let's say the image/tile is 32 pixels.

```
public static final tileSize = 32;
```

With this, we can now add tiles using a for loop:

```
for(int x = 0; x < SCREEN_WIDTH / GameTile.tileSize; x++) { // loop through as many tiles fit the x-axis.
    for(int y = 0; y < SCREEN_HEIGHT / GameTile.tileSize; y++) { // do the same with y-axis
        GameTile greenTile = new GameTile(0,true, x * GameTile.tileSize , y * GameTile.tileSize);
        gameWindow.add(greenTile);
     }
}
```

`SCREEN_WIDTH` and `SCREEN_HEIGHT` is the size of your JFrame.
Keep in mind this loops through the whole screen, you wanted the half but it's easily configurable.

Please format your code next time (tab in), much easier to read and help you.
I highly recommend moving `image = ImageIO.read(new File("greentile.png"));` into the constructor, right now you're loading the image every framerate for every gameTile which will cause performance drop.

Also do not have a JPanel for every GameTile. Instead keep it in your main drawing class and loop through all GameTiles using an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

```
public static ArrayList<GameTile> gameTiles = new ArrayList<GameTile>();

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    for(int i = 0; i < gameTiles.size(); i++) {
        gameTiles.get(i).draw(g);
    }
```

So instead of adding a JPanel to the JFrame for every gameTile, we draw gameTiles at the specified coordinates. Good luck!

**To answer your question in the comment field:** the code will look similar to this

```
public class GameWindow extends JPanel {

    public static ArrayList<GameTile> gameTiles = new ArrayList<GameTile>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GameWindow();
    }

    public GameWindow() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();    
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(this);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // add all the tiles (I just use x and y as parameters here)
        gameTiles.add(new GameTile(10, 10));
        gameTiles.add(new GameTile(50, 10));

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        for(int i = 0; i < gameTiles.size(); i++) {
            gameTiles.get(i).draw(g);
        }

    }

}
```

And inside your GameTile class, remove the `extends JPanel`. And rename the `paintComponent` as `draw` or something alike.

Comment: I'm implementing your code to see how it'll do, but at the (gameTiles.get(i).draw(g); line, there is an error where I have no draw method for the gameTiles class. I'm sorry for being such a noob, but GUI really gets me confused..

Comment: This is what I currently have (and I'm sorry I have no idea how to format code on these comments or in a post as you saw) 
    [[ protected void draw(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
         for(int i = 0; i < gameTiles.size(); i++) {
             gameTiles.get(i).draw(g);
         }
     } ]]
but the gameWindow will not paint anything when run.

Comment: Nevermind about the comment I just deleted, I figured it out! you are a life saver!

Answer (score 1):

> However, no matter what I try, the tiles are space so far apart, and change shape when I resize window

A GridLayout expands each cell to fill the space available to the component. If you only have two cells each cell will take up half the width of the frame.

So the solution is to wrap your tile panel into another panel that will respect the preferred size of the tiles. So don't set the layout of the frame, set the layout of a panel holding the tiles:

Something like:

```
JPanel tilePanel = new JPane( new GridLayout(0, 2, 5, 5) );
tilePanel.add( new GameTile(...) );
tilePanel.add( new GameTile(...) );

JPanel wrapper = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout() ); 
wrapper.add(tilePanel, new GridBagConstraints() );

frame.add(wrapper, BorderLayout.CENTER );
```

The above code will cause the tiles to be centered in the frame.

```
frame.add(wrapper, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
```

The above will cause the tiles to display on the right of the frame vertically centered.